# Is this list a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search

Is the following list a BST or not?

```
list:{2,5,3,8,6}
```

Is there a way I can determine this?

Consider that my list will have 100000 elements.

Comment: Wikipedia knows many of the basic data-type, including [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). However, if you have a *sorted list* you can run a [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on it. A Binary Search is an algorithm, not a data-type like a Binary Search Tree -- a BST must always be arranged valid (as a tree), by definition, but a list may not always be kept sorted (unless it's a "Sorted List" or something else ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer is: no. BST is a tree and you have a list.

Long answer is: it may be possible to encode a tree as a list, in which case, whether your list can be decoded into a tree or not will depend on the encoding algorithm. See BST wiki page for more details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

In fact your list may be an encoded version of BST. If you read elements from left to right pushing them onto a stack, and whenever you stack has 3 elements do:

```
parent = pop()
right = pop()
left = pop()
push new Node(parent, left, right)
```

then you should get a valid BST. But I am only speculating here.

Answer (score 1):

you are having a list , you need to construct BST from this list

A BST has following properties

1- Each node has two children or it is a leaf node

2- For each node its left subtree is smaller than node's value

3- For each node its right subtree is greater than node's value

a bst MUST BE BALANCED i.e. while inserting nodes in a BST , code must respect above 3 conditions.

Searching  in a BST is O(log n) operation that is because , each search step divide the search space into two halfs and choose one of the half.

There is a case where search will take O(N) time

Consider following

node = {1,2,3,4,5}

if we make the BST from this node set it will be right alifned that means every next node will be on the right subtree , here if we want to search for a item , we need to traverse whole right sub tree like a link list.